# JavaScript Namespace a function/class?

Tags: javascript, class, namespaces

So say I have a function like so:

```
function Moo()
{
    this.someVal = 'blah';

    return this;
}

Moo.prototype = 
{

}
```

If I instantiate an object from this class doing:

```
var moo = new Moo();

console.log(moo);
```

I get this in console, rather than the object with the someVal

```
Window www.domain.com
```

Comment: What you describe does not make sense. If you use `this` inside of the `Moo` constructor function or, say, a method `Moo.prototype.foo()`, it will refer to the instance of `Moo`. Please show an example of actual problematic code, describe what you expect to happen, and what *is* happening.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how he can set up a `myNameSpace.Moo` constructor.

Comment: Yes, I've updated it better, it was the window object not any this from parent object.

Comment: Are you sure you tried this? Here is a jsfiddle with your example. http://jsfiddle.net/qfYV2/ outputs an object with someVal = 'blah' as a property as expected.

Comment: Although the return statement in your constructor is completely unnecessary, I also don't see how it's possible to get a reference to window with your code sample. If you truly are seeing this, and it is replicated when you run the sample posted by @Mark , I have to ask what browser it is...

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot the "new", that's why I was getting the window obj instead of the function object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but here's an explanation that may help.

In plain javascript (i.e. ECMAScript), when a function is called with the [`new`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) operator, its `this` references a new object created as if by `new Object()` with its internal `[[Prototype]]` set to the constructor's public `prototype` object.

It is that new object that is returned (there is no need for `return this`, that is the default action), unless some other object is returned instead.

When a function is called, its `this` is set entirely by the call, the context (i.e. scope) is irrelevant.

So:

```
function Moo() {
  // if called with new, this references a new object
}

// Assign a new object to Moo.prototype,
// replacing the default object given to all functions
Moo.prototype = { 
  someMethod: function() {...},
  ...
} 

// Create an instance of Moo
var moo = new Moo();

// Call a method
moo.someMethod();
```

In the last line, `this` within `someMethod` will reference the `moo` object, but that is entirely based on how the method was called, it has nothing to do with how `moo` was constructed or the context from which it was called.

e.g. if `someMethod` is called as follows:

```
var x = moo.someMethod;

x();
```

The value of `this` has not been set, so in `someMethod` it will default to the global (window) object or, in strict mode, it will be undefined.

Note that the above occurs regardless of the context of the call, `this` is dynamic and set entirely by the call (ignoring [ES5 bind](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)).